# angular4+ how to change httpClient return body?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I hope the rxjs observable return only data, so I want to use HttpInterceptor to change the HttpResponse's body. the codes are

```
@Injectable()
export class NodeInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(
  req: HttpRequest<any>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(req).map(event => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      console.log(event);
      if (event.status === 200) {
        event.body = event.body.result;
      }
    }
    return event;
  });
} }
```

but show the body cannot be changed, how can i do that?

Comment: What are you trying to acheive with HttpInterceptor??  "I hope the rxjs observable return only data" what else you want to return?

Comment: I haven't personally tried this but you may be able to do `event = event.clone({ body: event.body.result });`. if it works I can re-post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting HttpInterceptor do what it is supposed to, You dont need to modify HttpInterceptor to return ResponseMessages in Angular.

This is how you can catch Response Messages from Api im Angular.

**In your service.ts**

```
 add(obj: Model): Observable<Model> {

        return this.http
        .post(this.url, item, { responseType: 'text' });

    }
```

**In you component**

```
 this.service.add(this.obj).subscribe(
        (value) => { this.response = value },
        (error) => { },
        () => {

            if (this.response === "Data saved successfully.") {
                // here you receive Response message.
            }

        });
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:
You can create a Generic HttpService and call it from all your components.**

@Injectable()

export class ApiServices {

```
url: string;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, config: APIConfig) {

    this.url = config.server + config.apiUrl;

}

public getAll(type: string): Observable<T[]> {

    return this.http
        .get(this.url + type)
            .map((res: any) => res);
}


public get<T>(type:string, id?: number): Observable<T> {

    return this.http
        .get<T>(this.url);
}


public add<T>(type:string, item: T): Observable<any> {

    return this.http
        .post(this.url + type, item, { responseType: 'text' });
}

public update<T>(type: string, item: T): Observable<any> {

    return this.http
        .put(this.url + type, JSON.stringify(item), { responseType: 'text' });
}

public delete<T>(id: number) {

    return this.http
        .delete <T>(this.url);
}
```

}

Comment: emmm, maybe I mistake HttpInterceptor, however my original intention is how to avoid every http service need a rxjs/map like http.get(url).map(result => { return result.data})

Comment: For that you can create a generic/shared HttpService with get, post, put, delete and call it from all your components.